# New Relic Silent installation on Amazon Linux 2 ARM 64 bit

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, newrelic, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to install New Relic PHP agent on Amazon Linux 2 (ARM 64) in silent mode but unfortunately it is getting into interactive mode. I have set the environment variables as mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/php-agent/advanced-installation/silent-mode-install-script-advanced/). Here are the steps I followed, am I missing something?

```
export NR_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/bin
export NR_INSTALL_SILENT=1
export NR_INSTALL_KEY=XXYYZZ

wget https://download.newrelic.com/php_agent/release/newrelic-php5-10.10.0.1-linux.tar.gz
gzip -dc newrelic-php5-10.10.0.1-linux.tar.gz | tar xf -
cd newrelic-php5-10.10.0.1-linux/
sudo ./newrelic-install install
```

Output (These steps are getting me into an interactive mode installation but I want to do a silent installation):

```
New Relic PHP Agent Installation (interactive mode)
===================================================

   Enter New Relic license key (or leave blank):
```

Answer (score 1):

Process started by sudo does not inherit the environment variables unless
explicitly configured to do so.

```bash
# Tell sudo to keep the desired environment variables with least contamination
sudo --preserve-env=NR_INSTALL_PATH,NR_INSTALL_SILENT,NR_INSTALL_KEY ./newrelic-install install

# Shorter command, but risk of contamination (especially PATH)
sudo -E ./newrelic-install install
```

In case the sudo user does not have permission to keep environment variables (sudoers security policy),
we can use `env` to set it manually.

```bash
sudo env NR_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/bin NR_INSTALL_SILENT=1 NR_INSTALL_KEY=XXYYZZ ./newrelic-install install
```